# Return array values which are not duplicates

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [
      {name:"Grace", age: "28"},
      {name:"Peter", age: "15"},
      {name:"Grace", age: "28"},
      {name:"John", age: "16"},
      {name:"Prince", age: "19"},
      {name:"John", age: "16"}
    ];
```

I now want return only those which are unique as below

```
var new = [
  {name:"Peter", age: "15"},
  {name:"Prince", age: "19"},
];
```

Comment: In `var new = [` the **`new`** is a reserved word. Use other variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` and `reduce`

- First create a `mapper` based on `name` and count repetition of each name
- Select only the values where repetition is exactly `1`

```js
const arr = [{name:"Grace", age: "28"},{name:"Peter", age: "15"},{name:"Grace", age: "28"},{name:"John", age: "16"},{name:"Prince", age: "19"},{name:"John", age: "16"}]; 

let mapper = arr.reduce( (op,inp) => {
  let {name:key} = inp
  op.set(key, op.get(key) || {value: inp, count:0})
  op.get(key).count++
  return op
},new Map())


let final = [...mapper.values()].reduce((op,{value,count}) => {
   if(count === 1){
    op.push(value)
   }
   return op
},[])

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @giuseppedeponte No the edit you suggested and question is not is sync. question asks for the unique values only, i.e. the value which occurs only once

Comment: Yes, my bad. But I could not retract my edit. You can reject it.